# Frameless Browser window zero height

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating a new frameless Browser window in Electron, with its height and width set at 0 but, at least in windows, the window is shown with some width and height.

Also i have not loaded any content inside.

```
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false,
    center: true,
    show: true,
    'use-content-size': false,
    'always-on-top': true
  });
```

Is it possible to have a frameless window with 0 height/width?

Comment: I'm curious, why create a browser window if you're trying to hide it?

Comment: @mscdex because I'm animating it's height and it needs to start at 0 height for the effect to look good.

Comment: Why not you add css3 scale animation to content?

Comment: @anhulife i don't have a content to animate, i want to animate the window itself. Even without a content the window does not have zero height.

Comment: Animating the window itself will be buggy and look bad. Set the window to a fixed size and animate the content inside the window

Comment: @PaulBetts I was able to animate it just fine, and with some easing it actually looks very good. If you meant the window content will be ugly on rescale i'd have to agree. Anyway my problem here is not the animation but the fact that a frameless window, in windows at least, does not start at zero height, even though i've set it to zero.

Answer (score -3):

Browsers don't allow you to do this
but you can do anything in hidden iframes
You can easily hide special iframe with css (display: none;)

I suggest you to use webworkers for background multi tasking